# Mapping beetween affine coordinate function

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

[image]

As the book says, an affine coordinate function of a line is $A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and represent the real number that, multiplied for a basis and starting from an origin of the line gives a certain point of the line, so a origin of the line and a basis is implicitly taken when defining the affine coordinate function.

Since for each of the 2 affine lines, the affine coordinate function is simply a number that is multiplied to the basis, what i think is that $f(\alpha )=r\alpha $. But this seems not to be correct. Why ?

> The book is :Paul Bamberg, ‎Shlomo Sternberg -  A Course in
>   Mathematics for Students of Physics Vol.1 . Pag 47 es 1.2

Comment: Added to the main post :)

Comment: As to the substance of your Question, simply multiplying by a (nonzero) scalar is not general enough.  One can also "shift" along a line, which is where the $...+s$ comes into "the most general formula" for $F$.

Comment: But, if a fix an origin for each line and a basis for each line , it's suficient $f(\alpha )=r\alpha $, in order to map every point from the first line to the second line. What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Affine lines do not have an "origin".  That's pretty much what makes an affine line different from a coordinate axis.

When you pick an affine coordinate function, you are assigning coordinates to points on the affine line in a uniform way.  Whichever point on the affine line happens to get the zero coordinate is chosen to the be origin *relative to that choice* of coordinate function, but it is not an intrinsic property of the affine line itself.

So there is no general requirement when one affine line is mapped onto to another affine line that some "origin" on the first affine line will map to an "origin" on the other affine line.

Therefore the *most general* form of relation from one affine coordinate function to another will have both the "scale" coefficient $r$ and the "shift translation" term $s$:

$$ F(\alpha) = r\alpha + s $$

Comment: In the book i'm using, an affine coordinate function is defined as a function $A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, so the output is a scalar. And also, the mapping function is $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ . Then, who carries the information about the origins and the basis of the 2 affine lines?

Comment: The choice of an affine coordinate function "carries the information" about the origin and "basis" for an affine line.  One point is assigned coordinate zero (the "origin") and another point is assigned coordinate one (the vector from the first point to the second is the basis for that line).  The same affine line can have infinitely many different coordinate functions.  The exercise you ask about requires the most general form of relationship between two coordinate functions for two affine lines, but you get the same form of relationship between two coordinate functions for the *same* line.

Comment: See the discussion at bottom of page 15 of the book you are using.  It explains "Thus we construct an *affine coordinate function* $$ x:\mathbb A \to \mathbb R $$ Of course, there are many possible affine coordinate functions on a line, and which one we construct depends on our origin and unit of measurement."

Comment: So, in $f(\alpha )=r\alpha +s$, what does r and s represent ?

Comment: They are real numbers.  $r $ needs to be nonzero, but  $s $ can be any real number.

Comment: Suppose we have 2 affine lines (NOT paralells), for each line we set an arbitrary origin and an arbitrary basis. I choose a point P in the first line and i get x(P) = 3. Then, I choose an arbitrary point P' in the second line , and i get y(P') = 1 . So, the mapping beetween the first line and the second line is  $F(\alpha) = \alpha/3 $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75732/discussion-between-hardmath-and-qwerto).